# How to sort weights in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an array list of `List<string>` that contains values in the following order `[100g, 1.5kg, 250g]` now when I try to sort them I am not getting the expected result and it is sorting in the following order.

I am using `array.OrderBy(x => x);`

```
[1.5kg, 100g, 250g]
```

How can I sort them according to their weight?

the correct should be:

```
[100g, 250g, 1.5kg]
```

Comment: what struct you have ?

Comment: how do you know it "g" or "kg" ?

Comment: that is what I am asking @TimChang. How do I make it know that g is gram and kg is kilo gram and gram is a smaller unit

Comment: what "struct" in array?

Comment: can you post full code ? with array.OrderBy(x => x);

Comment: I am using List<string>

Comment: I you just use strings, you are sorting alphabetically

Answer (score 3):

try parse to g and sort it

```
   public void GOGO()
{
    List<string> ay = new List<string>()
    {
        "1.5kg","100g","1600g"
    };
    IOrderedEnumerable<string> orderList = ay.OrderBy(x => WeightG(x));
    foreach(string s in orderList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);//here
    }
}

public int WeightG(string weighStr)
{
    if (weighStr.Contains("kg"))
    {
        string num = weighStr.Split('k')[0];
        return (int)(float.Parse(num) * 1000);
    }

    if (weighStr.Contains("g"))
    {
        string num = weighStr.Split('g')[0];
        return int.Parse(num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize all array elements to g. Then sort as numbers and finally convert to g or kg.

sample code:

```
    private string[]  normalaizeArray(string[] inputArray)
    {
        for (int i= 0 ; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(inputArray[i].Contains('k'))
            {
                inputArray[i] = (float.Parse(inputArray[i].Split('k')[0]) * 1000).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                inputArray[i] = inputArray[i].Replace("g", "");
            }
        }
        inputArray = inputArray.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(int.Parse(inputArray[i])>1000)
                inputArray[i] = (float.Parse(inputArray[i])/1000).ToString() + "kg";
            else
                inputArray[i] = inputArray[i] + 'g';
        }
        return inputArray;
    }
```

[image]
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler and elegant solution with less code:

```
string[] a = new string[] { "7.2kg", "1.5kg", "100g", "250g" };
var lstKg = a.ToList().Where(x => x.Contains("kg")).Select(y => double.Parse(y.Replace("kg", String.Empty))).OrderBy(k=>k).Select(o=>o+"kg").ToList();
var lstG = a.ToList().Where(x => !lstKg.Contains(x)).Select(y => double.Parse(y.Replace("g", String.Empty))).OrderBy(k=>k).Select(o =>o+"g").ToList();
lstG.AddRange(lstKg);
lstG.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

Comment: What if `"1.5kg"` is replaced with `"0.2kg"` in `a`?

Comment: @Astrid E - It doesn't mention this in his request. The assumption is that it will be set at grams. U can assume further that he works also with 'mg'.  So yes, my algorithm works only if the the Kg items are above 1 and the those below are defined with grams.

Comment: I agree that your approach solves the specific example that was posted in the question.